# How to wake up a device from sleep by pin?

Tags: embedded, sleep, microcontroller, pic, microchip

How would you configure a pin to wake a device up from sleep by changing its state?

I know how to wake up a device from sleep with the WDT but I also need to wake it up by setting a pin high. I have [PIC18F87J11](http://seniordesign.ee.nd.edu/2008/Design%20Teams/Awesome-o/datasheets/39778b.pdf) and I am using MPLAB C18.
Thanks!

Comment: What you're looking for is an "External Interrupt" source.  If you look through your linked datasheet you'll find you have 4 external interrupt sources (INT0, 1, 2, 3).  So you'd configure one of these for a Rising Edge, and ensure the interrupt is enabled.  See section 9.6.

Comment: The thing is interrupts are disabled during sleep mode, so I would need an external oscillator for it to work, so I am trying to do it without using oscillator, thus by pin changing state.

Comment: Without digging too much into the datasheet, I'm not sure your statement is correct.  "When a wake event occurs in Sleep mode (by interrupt,Reset or WDT time-out)" is text from section 3.3, so interrupts must be able to wake sleep mode.  Perhaps not external interrupts, but some interrupts can do it.

Comment: In section 9.6, it says that "All external interrupts (INT0, INT1, INT2 and INT3) can wake-up the processor from the power-managed
modes if bit INTxIE was set prior to going into the power-managed modes." Also in section 10.3, PORTB with interrupt on change feature,"This interrupt can wake the device from power-managed modes." Normally PIC can wake up from sleep using these interrupts.

Comment: @ponnus I have internal oscillator so my interrupts are considered internal and not external, right? So the interrupts will be off during sleep mode. Plus I am trying to wake up the device with a pin change, so I guess my best option is to go with MCLR pin. Thanks for taking the time to look at the datasheet.

Comment: Usually PICs can wake up from sleep using interrupts with internal oscillator. Try simulating your code using MPLABSIM, then you'll be able to know it.

Comment: ponnus is right. I have used features like INTx and PORTB interrupt on change to wake PIC from sleep on many projects. It works whether you use internal or external oscillator. MCLR would not be a good solution if you need to continue a job, because it reset the PIC and you loose state.

Comment: Would it be right to use any of the following pins to wake up the device from sleep ? `RB4` or `RB5` or `RB6` or `RB7`. I just need a confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Interrupt on Change" function from your PIC. It is well explained in this MicroChip document :
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00566b.pdf

Comment: Would it be right to use any of the following pins to wake up the device from sleep ? `RB4` or `RB5` or `RB6` or `RB7`. Those pins are Interrupt-on-change pins,I just need a confirmation.